# interface conversion: interface {} is int64, not []uint8

Tags: json, go, interface, nested, httpresponse

I'm trying to implement a go program which can handle http requests and send response in nested JSON. When i run my code and call the URL, I'm getting a runtime error,what does it mean? how can i handle this?

```
panic serving 192.168.0.101:50760: interface conversion: interface {} is int64, not []uint8
goroutine 5 [running]
```

This is my function code which is called on hitting the url

```
func logInPass(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    type Resp struct {
        Result []map[string]interface{} `json:"Result,omitempty"`
        Status string                   `json:"Status"`
    }
    type AxleUser struct {
        Mobile   string `json:"Mobile"`
        Password string `json:"Password"`
    }

    var Response Resp
    Response.Status = "failed"
    Result := make(map[string]interface{})
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:chikkIbuddI57@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/b2b")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rnd := render.New()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    defer req.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // Unmarshal the request body
    var msg AxleUser
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // get shop id from emp table using mobile number and password
    userrows, usererr := db.Query("SELECT b2b_emp_id,b2b_shop_id,b2b_shop_name,b2b_emp_name,b2b_emp_mobile_number FROM b2b_employee_tbl WHERE b2b_emp_mobile_number=? and b2b_password=?", msg.Mobile, msg.Password)
    if usererr != nil {
        panic(usererr.Error())
    }
    usercolumns, usererr := userrows.Columns()
    if usererr != nil {
        panic(usererr.Error())
    }

    usercount := len(usercolumns)
    values := make([]interface{}, usercount)
    scanArgs := make([]interface{}, usercount)
    for i := range values {
        scanArgs[i] = &values[i]
    }
    for userrows.Next() {
        usererr := userrows.Scan(scanArgs...)
        if usererr != nil {
            panic(usererr.Error())
        }
        for i, v := range values {
            if v != nil {
                Result[usercolumns[i]] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(v.([]byte)))
            }
        }
        Response.Result = append(Response.Result, Result)
        Response.Status = "success"
    }

    res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    rnd.JSON(res, http.StatusOK, Response)
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The error message and stack trace says that you need to fix your code at the 88th line in file C:/axle2.0/testinghttp/apicall.go, on that line you're attempting to type assert an interface value as `[]uint8` while it's true underlying type is `int64`. When doing type assertion, to avoid panics, use the "comma ok" idiom, if you're unfamiliar with what that is google will help you.

Comment: @siri read my previous comment and then fix this line `Result[usercolumns[i]] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(v.([]byte)))`. In Go `byte` is an alias for `uint8`, see here: https://play.golang.org/p/Yt0u6KgAwTc.

Comment: And btw, `fmt.Sprintf` already knows how to handle values of different types, you can fix that line by simply doing this `Result[usercolumns[i]] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", v)`.

Comment: @siri My mistake, change `%s` to `%v` in Sprintf's format string.

Comment: @mkopriva now all my data values are in bytes like "[43 57 49 57 53 53 49 51 51 51 51 50 50]"

Comment: I don't know how you want to retrieve/store/display your data, since you didn't include that in the original question. Your question was about a runtime error which you've now resolved. If there is a different problem that you don't know how to resolve please start a new question with information about that problem and what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: @mkopriva Chill dude, thanks for helping me. I need to send the data in json string format. I think I've mentioned it in the question. Anyways, thanks again .

Comment: If you want to turn the result into json then do not convert each individual value to a string, instead you should keep the values unchanged and then marshal the whole thing at once. Do this `Result[usercolumns[i]] = v` instead, then after you have the whole result use the `encoding/json` package to marshal it into valid json. Even better would be to define proper struct types that would represent the table records, scan query results into values of those structs, and then marshal those.

Comment: @mkopriva it works! thanks.This is a smaller use case, but there might be huge data from some table, so i prefer to make it dynamic instead of defining a struct type for the required columns.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed this line

```
values := make([]interface{}, usercount)
```

To

```
values := make([]string, usercount)
```

And this line

```
Result[usercolumns[i]] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(v.([]byte)))
```

To

```
Result[usercolumns[i]] = v
```